# Using setSelected on a textView inside a listItem inside a listView

Tags: android, textview, marquee

I'm trying to get scrolling text (marquee) happening inside a listview, but from my previous reading it seems I need to use setSelected(true) on my textview.

Because the textview is inside listitem instead of listview, I can't seem to use getView on that textView, and thus can't use setSelected.

I'll try and explain with some code:

Here is my oncreate:

```
setContentView(R.layout.albumsview);



    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String where = extras.getString("where");
    String[] whereVal = extras.getStringArray("whereVal");

    String[] columns = { BaseColumns._ID, AudioColumns.ALBUM, };

    String orderBy = BaseColumns._ID;

    albumCursor = managedQuery(
            MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, where,
            whereVal, orderBy);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewAlbums);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    String[] displayFields = new String[] { AudioColumns.ALBUM };
    int[] displayViews = new int[] { R.id.albumTitle };
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
    R.layout.albumitem, albumCursor, displayFields, displayViews);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The "albumTitle" is the view containing the textview (called subTitle) which I want to setSelected(true).

Could someone please show me how to do this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Simple Adapter than u have to make custome TextView  and than add it in your xml as given below

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView{

 public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
    rotate();
  }

public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
    rotate();
  }

public MyTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
    rotate();
  }

private void rotate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    setSelected(true);
  }

private void init() {
    if (!isInEditMode()) {

    }
  }


 }
```

and than add custome textview in Your **albumitem.xml** as shown below

```
 <Your Package Name.MyTextView
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip" android:id="@+id/tv_parse"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="22px"
    android:textColor="#34A4c5"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:maxWidth="220dp" 
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"  
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"></Your Package Name.MyTextView>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Khan. any ideas why I'm getting com.myactivity.ArtistAlbumsActivity.MyTextView could not be instantiated in my xml view?

Comment: Never mind, I'd added it as a method, rather than a new class.

Answer (score 1):

I also had a similar need and came up with the following approach. I implemented `SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder` in my activity. It is a single method that looks like this `public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex)`. Inside I get the id from the View. If it is the correct one, I cast it to a `TextView` and `setText();` on it followed by `setSelected(true)` and return true. On views I'm not interested in, I return false and let `TextView` handle it. No need to create a custom `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get each view record in your list, using `getChildCount()` and `getChildAt(i)`  Here are my example

```
View getViewPattern;
    TextView getTextByPattern;
    String contentAnswerInPattern;
    for (int i = 0; i < listView.getChildCount(); i++) {
        getViewPattern = listView.getChildAt(i);
        getTextByPattern = (TextView) getViewPattern.findViewById(R.id.value_a);
        contentAnswerInPattern = getTextByPattern.getText().toString().trim();
    }
```