# TextView Marquee not working in android

Tags: android, textview

I have trying to use marquee and its not working,
Here is my code... can anyone see the problem?

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblTitle" 

        android:ellipsize="marquee" 
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:focusable="true" 
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
        android:freezesText="true"

        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:text="Book Title"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="12dp" />
```

i set text of this textview at run time.
i use code from this link
[TextView Marquee not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332924/textview-marquee-not-working)

Comment: can try with some bigger text than "Book Title" ?

Comment: yes i try it but it's not done..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just do this way in ur activity as ur code is ok for that for simple textview marquee

```
TextView textview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblTitle);
textview.setSelected(true);
```

and if u want to use marquee in listview in adapter than check answer given at [Marquee in listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861257/using-setselected-on-a-textview-inside-a-listitem-inside-a-listview/10861397#10861397)

Comment: this is the solution. others don't work. The view must be set selected for marquee to work. NOTE that selected is different from focused.

Comment: Is it possible to extend TextView and add it by default? for some reason it crashed for me when i tried to use "setSelected" in "setEllipsize" .

Answer (score 4):

```
working on my phone 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblTitle" 

            android:ellipsize="marquee" 
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:focusable="true" 
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
            android:freezesText="true"

            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text="Book Title sad ds sdas das asdas das asd asd sad as"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="12dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: yes i create new project and its working, but in my project i use this textview in custom list view and is not working .

Comment: g8.. so can you update you full layout to get to know about layout to find the issue....

Comment: have you tired with tv.setSelected(true); ? in you big layout

Comment: that's gr8.. you can up-vote my answer but I think right answer acceptance deserved by the Khan below... :)

Answer (score 3):

This code working for you.

```
<TextView
    android:text="START | lunch 20.00 | Dinner 60.00 | Travel 60.00 | Doctor 5000.00 | lunch 20.00 | Dinner 60.00 | Travel 60.00 | Doctor 5000.00 | END"
    android:id="@+id/MarqueeText" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true" 
    android:paddingLeft="15dip" 
    android:paddingRight="15dip" 
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
    android:freezesText="true">
</TextView>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I test it and it is working. another think without log text (test width must large then phone width) it is not wotking and aslo need android 1.5 and above

Answer (score 1):

This code works

```
<TextView
android:text="A very long book title"
android:id="@+id/book_title" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="marquee" 
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
android:scrollHorizontally="true" 
android:paddingLeft="15dip" 
android:paddingRight="15dip" 
android:focusable="true" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
android:freezesText="true">
```

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same problem.
Khan's answer is right, but sometimes
    textview.setSelected(true);
doesn't work when the text view can't get the focus all the time.
So, to ensure TextView Marquee working, I had to use a custom TextView.

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {
    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
        if(focused)
            super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean focused) {
        if(focused)
            super.onWindowFocusChanged(focused);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isFocused() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And then, you can use the custom TextView as the scrolling text view in your layout .xml file like this:

```
<com.example.myapplication.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvScrollingMessage"
            android:text="@string/scrolling_message_main_wish_list"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:freezesText="true"/>
```

NOTE: in the above code snippet com.example.myapplication is an example package name and should be replaced by your own package name.

Hope this will help you.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This line of code is working 100%, Just put these lines inside your textview xml code, it will start works

```
 android:singleLine="true" 
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```